# How to set up a shortcut for different versions of R in RStudio?

Tags: r, configuration, rstudio

Using Rstudio, it is [easy to configure it](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/advanced/versions_of_r) for different versions of R.  You simply navigate to `/Tools/Options` and select your preferred version of R.

But is there an easy way to set up a menu (or desktop) shortcut or a command line script to point to different versions of R?

My use case is that I frequently want to run and compare scripts in different versions of R, e.g:

- R-2.15.3
- R-devel (R-3.0.0)

It would be useful to set this up as a single click shortcut, rather than navigating the menus each time.

(I appreciate this may well be better suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com/) but in my view the answer to this question is more likely to be found here, at StackOverflow.)

**What should I do to configure such a shortcut?**

Additional information: I am running Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't you just hold down control when you click on your desktop shortcut?

From [the link you posted](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/advanced/versions_of_r):

> Note that by holding down the Control key during the launch of RStudio you can cause the R version selection dialog to display at startup.

Comment: holding down control works as a charm, many thanks